"Oh no, something has gone wrong" on Ubuntu 24.04.1 after upgrade when switching off the screen
After upgrading my system to Ubuntu 24.04.1, if the screen goes black (e.g. when I switch off the screen) and I switch it on again, all my open windows will be displayed incorrectly, and I cannot interact normally with them. After few clicks, I obtain the infamous message:
"Oh no, something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred, and the system can’t recover" with the log-out button.
How can I solve this issue?
Additional information that I think are related to the issue:

I am using a Hp tower Z2 Workstation

I had a really hard time upgrading my system. When I did, upon restarting my workstation, the system was broken, and it was impossible to access the graphic interface. I had to run a series of commands from the ttyl to solve the issue. At that time, I was getting the same "Oh no, something has gone wrong message whenever I was trying to Ctrl-alt-F1 in the graphical interface". I solved by reiterating the following commands until the upgrade process was completed.



sudo apt --fix-missing 
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade 
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove

After that, I updated the Nvidia graphic drivers.

If I connect the screen to the motherboard (as opposed to the Nvidia graphic card), the problem does not occur

If I try to Ctrl-alt-F3 to a tty the screen freeze (apparently the tty is running but I cannot see it -> if I log in and reboot the system reboots)

By running



sudo apt update --fix-missing

I get the following warnings:

W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jiayi/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jiayi' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

